# Get Airport code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use jquery for airport code its working fine with country, But i want airport code by city name. But this is not working. I am doing this by json.
Here is my code, Please tell me, What's wrong in my code.

```
  <script>
  function buildQuery(term) {
    return "select * from json where url = 'http://airportcode.riobard.com/search?  fmt=JSON&q=" + encodeURI(term) + "'";
   }

   function makeRequest(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
      data: {
        q: buildQuery(request.term),
        format: "json"
     },
     dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function(data) {
        var airports = [];
        if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.json &&  data.query.results.json.json) {
            airports = data.query.results.json.json;
        }

        response($.map(airports, function(item) {
            return {
                label: item.code + (item.name ? ", " + item.name : "") ,
                value: item.code
            };
        }));
     },
      error: function () {
        response([]);
        }
     });
   }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#airport").autocomplete({
       source: makeRequest,
      minLength: 2
    });
  });
</script>

<input id="airport" />


<!-- HTML Code is -->
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: actually its show airport code when we enter particular city like (London, United Kingdom) its show wrong result